# Rewriting xyz as combination of squares

Tags: linear-algebra, problem-solving

It is well-known that $xy=\frac{1}{4}[(x+y)^2-(x-y)^2]$. However for the problem I am currently working, I need to write $xyz$ as a lineal combination of squares or cubes of $\{\pm x\pm y \pm z\}$.

Any ideas on how to do so?

Edit: As it was pointed to me in the comments, you can't do it with just cuadratics, but I'm still interested in knowing how this might be done with the addition of cubes

Comment: $xyz$ is cubic in $x$, $y$, $z$.

Comment: I know, that this imply there is no way to do it with squares?

Comment: You never get degree 3 terms from quadratic.

Comment: Oh okay, I'll correct that

Comment: Using polarization identity first on $xyz$ you get $xyz= \frac 1 4(z(x+y)^2-z(x-y)^2)$. Then applying it on $z(x+y)^2$ and $z(x-y)^2$ you get a hodge-podge of squares (of squares). Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: @Sisyphus I had thought of this, however I wouldn't call this a linear combination. And it seems to me to be quite "clumpsy"

Comment: You can write it in quartic function by putting $"xy"$ as first term and $z$ as second

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$ x y z = \frac{1}{24}\left( (x+y+z)^3 - (x+y-z)^3 -(x-y+z)^3 -(-x+y+z)^3 \right)  \text{.}  $$

Comment: That looks like it should work, thanks a bunch